# Complete residue system modulo n (permutation of numbers 0 to n-1) such that

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, additive-combinatorics

I have a task: 
Find all $n\ \epsilon \ N, \ n > 1$ for which a permutation $a_1,\ a_2,\ ...,\ an\ $ of numbers $ 0,1, ..., n - 1$ exists such that $a_1,\ a_1+a_2,\ ...,\ a_1+a_2+\ ...\ +an\ $ form a CRS $mod\ n$.

So far I've come to the conclusion that $a_1$ must be $0$ because otherwise there would be two equal numbers from the listed above (so it won't be a CRS) and I think that odd numbers don't form CRS because $n*(n-1)/2 \ \ (mod\ n)$ is also $0$ so again won't form CRS. My assumption is that all **even** numbers can form CRS and satisfy the conditions above since I have found such permutations for numbers 2,4,6,8, but I don't know how to prove it and if it is right at all.

Would appreciate some help: first - whether I have made any mistakes so far, and second - with proof if I am right.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say that odd numbers don't work but prime numbers do work...?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say **even**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question is about *sequenceable groups*, [introduced in 1961](http://msp.org/pjm/1961/11-4/pjm-v11-n4-p14-p.pdf) by Basil Gordon.

A finite group is called *sequenceable* if its elements can be written as a sequence $(g_1,g_2,\dotsc,g_n)$ so that all the partial products $g_1,g_1g_2,\dotsc,g_1g_2\dotsb g_n$ are pairwise distinct. Gordon has shown that a finite *abelian* group is sequenceable if and only if it contains exactly one involution (element of order $2$). It is easily seen that this condition is necessary, and Gordon proved that it is also sufficient.

A great review of this subject can be found in [this paper](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/viewFile/DS10/pdf) by Matt Ollis; see also more recent papers by the same author, such as [this one](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/d7fd4cccd8e6599bd0c8091f6047bd12/adm545.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the materials! I've seen similar problem, with products and not sums, but I don't understand it well enough to be able to apply it to my problem with the sums.

Comment: @vixenn: Seva completely answered your question (his product is your sum), so I suggest that you accept his answer officially (so that it turns green).

Comment: Reading the materials a little bit more thoroughly, I think I understand it better now. Thanks for the help, @Seva :)